# How to upload files in Activiti-Modeler?

Tags: file-upload, activiti, bpmn

I want add File Upload function in Activiti-Modeler. Which method is the simplest?

Answer (score 0):

Which modeler?
Eclipse
Kiss PM
Angular Modeler

Greg

Comment: I believe I already answered that here in the Alfresco/Activiti forum:

https://community.alfresco.com/thread/228259-activiti-modeler

Activiti Explorer 5.12-5.22 includes model upload.

Comment: This should be a comment instead of answer